# Unable to parse JSON from Telnyx Api

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I am developing an endpoint in C# to accept JSON posted from an external provider (Telnyx).  Here is a sample of the data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "event_type": "fax.received",
    "id": "e15c28d4-147e-420b-a638-2a2647315577",
    "occurred_at": "2021-11-19T16:37:02.863682Z",
    "payload": {
      "call_duration_secs": 35,
      "connection_id": "1771912871052051547",
      "direction": "inbound",
      "fax_id": "2a168c93-3db5-424b-a408-b70a3da625bc",
      "from": "+12399999999",
      "media_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/faxes-prod/999",
      "page_count": 1,
      "partial_content": false,
      "status": "received",
      "to": "+12399999999",
      "user_id": "dc6e79fa-fe3b-462b-b3a7-5fb7b3111b8a"
    },
    "record_type": "event"
  },
  "meta": {
    "attempt": 1,
    "delivered_to": "https://webhook.site/27ef892c-c371-4976-ae22-22deea57080e"
  }
}
```

I have verified this is valid JSON through https://jsonlint.com/.  I created a model:

```
public class myDeserializedClass
{
    public class Payload
    {
        public int call_duration_secs { get; set; }
        public string connection_id { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public string fax_id { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string media_url { get; set; }
        public int page_count { get; set; }
        public bool? partial_content { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string event_type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime occurred_at { get; set; }
        public Payload payload { get; set; }
        public string record_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int attempt { get; set; }
        public string delivered_to { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller being posted to looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InboundFax(myDeserializedClass json)
{
    try
    {
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json.ToString().Trim());
        return Content("OK");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am receiving the error: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: K. Path '', line 0, position 0.` each time the API tries to post to my endpoint.  I have also tried posting data using Postman and receive the same error message.  Additionally, there are examples of JSON posting on the API website at https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/programmable-fax/tutorials/receive-a-fax-via-api.  Since my application fails with both postman and real-time API calls, I'm am working on the assumption the problem is my code, but can't be 100% certain and don't know how to fix it.  This is a mission critical problem that I need to solve.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi again! I understand now. Lets try simplify the things. First at all, when you debug, is json well filled with data on the input myDeserializedClass?

Comment: I think I understand now what is the problem. Please review my update, how I formatted the classes without a class inside another one. And how you implement that class

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the class is bad. Should be:

```
public class Payload
{
    public int call_duration_secs { get; set; }
    public string connection_id { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
    public string fax_id { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string media_url { get; set; }
    public int page_count { get; set; }
    public bool? partial_content { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string event_type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime occurred_at { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
    public string record_type { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int attempt { get; set; }
    public string delivered_to { get; set; }
}

public class myDeserializedClass
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

It depends on the data that you are getting, but if you are getting the object, you don't need to convert it to work:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InboundFax(myDeserializedClass json)
{
    try
    {
        //Work directly with json as object, forget "root" is: myDeserializedClass
        return Content("OK");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

or if you are getting the json as string:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InboundFax(string json)
{
    try
    {
        //Work directly with json as object
 myDeserializedClass myInstance= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myDeserializedClass>(json);
  
        return Content("OK");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE AFTER TESTING IT:**

I test it with a dummy controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InboundFax(myDeserializedClass json)
        {
            try
            {
                //Just dummy test
                if (json.meta.attempt == 1)
                {
                    return Content("OK");
                }
                else {
                    return Content("NO");
                }
                //Work directly with json as object, forget "root" is: myDeserializedClass
              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

in a HomeController (blank template from MVC Web just dummy)

So posting to:

```
https://localhost:44334/Home/InboundFax
```

METHOD: `POST`

With the following data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "event_type": "fax.received",
    "id": "e15c28d4-147e-420b-a638-2a2647315577",
    "occurred_at": "2021-11-19T16:37:02.863682Z",
    "payload": {
      "call_duration_secs": 35,
      "connection_id": "1771912871052051547",
      "direction": "inbound",
      "fax_id": "2a168c93-3db5-424b-a408-b70a3da625bc",
      "from": "+12399999999",
      "media_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/faxes-prod/999",
      "page_count": 1,
      "partial_content": false,
      "status": "received",
      "to": "+12399999999",
      "user_id": "dc6e79fa-fe3b-462b-b3a7-5fb7b3111b8a"
    },
    "record_type": "event"
  },
  "meta": {
    "attempt": 1,
    "delivered_to": "https://webhook.site/27ef892c-c371-4976-ae22-22deea57080e"
  }
}
```

Little quickwatch you see it map everything:

[image: QUICKWATCH]

Could mean the POSTMAN is wrong configurated?

I use the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

[image: REST CLIENT]

I'm using TALEND API TESTER for Chrome, but every REST client is similar

With POSTMAN, same result, OK. Check for body: raw, type JSON, and header with the content type applicantion/json

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for all of your help.  I created the class DeserializedClass and copied the class you posted.  Then: ```        public IActionResult InboundFax(DeserializedClass json)
        {
            try
            {
                return Content(json.data.payload.ToString());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(ex.ToString());
            }
        }``` but when posting with Postman, receive an object not set to reference error.  Were you able to make this work?

Comment: @Greybeard No problem No, I can't use the API without paying :S

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand you. You are posting to your own service as if the API? Could I see the example entire with headers and everything?

Comment: Correct.  I am posting to my own service just like the api does.  The data is the same posted earlier in this thread.  I also tried using the api and received the same error.  So I am wondering if you tried simply posting the data using Postman and go it to work.  All the code and data I am using is in this post.

Comment: Ok, fine.  will test it tomorrow, is very late here. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Greybeard it seems to be everthing OK, please view mhy update and the images. I think it can be the postman. But the mapping is ok.

Comment: @Greybeard same result with postman. It's ok. I will update with POSTMAN image also

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.  Still not working either with Postman or the api.  Postman is sending application/json and using the same data as earlier in this post.

Comment: @Greybeard It can be some problem of infraestructure? Could you get the data in the debug mode?

Comment: @Greybeard A suggestion use the code that I use to test it

Comment: Would you be able to try posting the data to my controller?  Also, I sent you an email.

Comment: @Greybeard got it!!! Is very late here right now, Ill answer you tomorrow!

Comment: Btw, quickwatch is shoing both data and meta as null.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if I have an answer or not, however, I did manage to get the application working by changing the endpoint to a WebApi instead of a MVC controller.  I was under the impression a MVC controller could accept json data, however, I was unable to ever get it working.  Once I changed it, everyting worked perfectly.